# How to set ranges and limits for multiple inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, validation

I have three inputs x, y and z. How do I set limits for these inputs? Also if I want x to be always greater than y, but less than z how can I do this?

```
while True:
    try: 

        x, y, z = (float(i) for i in input("Please input the x(meters), y (meters), z, respectively seperated with space:").split())                     
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter values without commas!") 

    if x > 0:
        print("X must be < 0")
    if x < y or x > z:
        print("x must be greater than y but less than z!")
    else:
        break
```

This code does not work correctly!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Here I want to set multiple ranges? I think it is different!

Comment: The solution would be same.

Comment: I tried using try and except twice but that did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems right. You just need to add `continue`

**Code**

```py
while True:
    try:
        x, y, z = (float(i) for i in input("Please input the x(meters), y (meters), z, respectively seperated with space:").split())  
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter values without commas!") 
    if x > 0:
        print("X must be < 0")
        continue
    if x < y or x > z:
        print("x must be greater than y but less than z!")
        continue
    else:
        break
```